# Weird performance in matrix multiplication using AMP dependent on memory layout

Tags: c++, directx, c++-amp

I started experimenting with AMP - Accelerated Massive Parallelism library by Microsoft.

I wrote code to compute C = A * B (or C = A*B^T).

My CPU intuition suggests that having a transposed B matrix as input should provide a great performance increase. The loops and accesses would then be:
`for(y) for(x) for(k) C[y][x] = A[y][k] * B[x][k];`

When run on GPU, this variant is an order of magnitude slower than the one without transposition - having `B[k][x]` lowers running time from 700ms to 100ms.

This makes no sense for me. Can anyone explain this behavior? More generally, what are memory layout rules for writing performant GPU algorithms?

Code producing above results: https://gist.github.com/Noxitu/d961889140691693072562eac08e50bc

(I think AMP is installed with Visual Studio by default.)

(Note that code claims that most of time is spent in "synchronize" call, but due to consistency of my benchmarks I belive it must be that `parallel_for_each` is an asynchronous operation.)

Comment: "My CPU intuition suggests that having a transposed B matrix" ? Why? Sorry but this doesnt make sense. Just consider that `A == transpose( transpose( A ))`, so you could apply the same argument to the transpose and say "using the doubly transposed (ie the original matrix) should be more efficient than the transposed"

Comment: If you implement literally matrix multiplication for each cell you are traversing a single column. Since matrices are by convention stored row-wise you are reading all over entire memory.


By transposing second matrix I essentially mean to store second matrix column-wise. This means that calculation of single cell involves computing inner product of two **continous** arrays - which is much faster on CPU than naive variant.

Comment: ok now i get it *facepalm*. The 700ms/100ms is the sum of the two times you print in the code, right?

Comment: btw you should include the code in the question